# Eloquent get top 5 records from each group

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get top 5 records from each category using Eloquent query, similar to sample MySQL query as follows;

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secid ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS n
    FROM trees
) AS x
WHERE n <= 5
```

This is what I tried

```
  $q= Tree::select(['*',DB::raw("ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secid ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS n")])
         ->WhereRaw(['n','<=','5'])
```

->select();

I'm getting "Array to string conversion" error

I tried

```
->WhereRaw('n','<=','5')
```

and getting

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 n order by `trees`.`created_at` desc' at line 1
```

Can anyone please point me what am I doing wrong here?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the `whereRow` method is an sql string and the second is an array of bindings.
To avoid this error you need the following call:

```
->whereRaw('n <= ?', [5])
```

But still the query will not build correctly. I suggest you use the following construction:

```
$subQuery = DB::table('trees')
    ->selectRaw('*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secid) AS n')
    ->orderByDesc('created_at');

$result = DB::fromSub($subQuery, 'x')
    ->where('n', '<=', 5)
    ->get();
```

Solution with Eloquent:

```
$subQuery = Tree::selectRaw('*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY secid) AS n')
    ->orderByDesc('created_at');

$result = Tree::fromSub($subQuery, 'trees')
    ->where('n', '<=', 5)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. My actual query is written in Eloquent and it's much bigger than the query I posted. The only part I used DB:: is to get the row number. Is there any way to get that part using Eloquent syntax, or should I rewrite whole query in SQL way? It's great if I can use Eloquent syntax.

Comment: added a solution for eloquent